# How to create a hook for a module in a theme?

Tags: 8, hooks, theming

I am trying to alter some data that is being passed from the `Language Switcher` module.

Here is a code snippet from the module.

```
if (isset($links->links)) {
  $build = array(
    '#theme' => 'links__language_block',
    '#links' => $links->links,
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        "language-switcher-{$links->method_id}",
      ),
    ),
    '#set_active_class' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

So `'#theme' => 'links__language_block',` as I could guess means that I have to create the function called

```
function mytheme_links__language_block(&$variables) {
    var_dump("HELLO");
    exit;
}
```

But it is not called. I have no idea what is the problem ?

The only hook is called - `function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables)`

Please suggest what can be wrong and why my hook function is not called.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your function. The theme hook uses *language_block* but your function name is using *locale_block*.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error, but this is not a problem, just typo in the question

Comment: Have to ask the obvious - did you clear cache after adding this code?

Comment: @Kevin , I have just cleared it before reading your comment and it works, but I have enabled development mode !! Why it is still caching this files ? 
Could you please explain how to disable this cache. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this style of theme hook is deprecated in Drupal 8. From the [API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/themeable/8.2.x):

> Theme functions are deprecated in Drupal 8.0.x and will be removed before Drupal 9.0.x. Use Twig templates instead.

So since there doesn't exist a theme function `theme_links()`, the functions `MYTHEME_links` and `MYTHEME_links__language_block` would not be called.

You can still customize this output by adding a `links--language-block.html.twig` file to your theme.

You can also utilize preprocess functions (`MYTHEME_preprocess_links()`).

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you add functions and template files to your theme, you should clear the cache so the functions and templates are picked up by Drupal.

Comment: Is there any way to disable this cache ? I have followed this tutorial, but still as you can see it caches https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914